# Why does re.findall() find more matches than re.sub()?

Tags: python, regex

Consider the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "first:second"
>>> re.findall("[^:]*", a)
['first', '', 'second', '']
>>> re.sub("[^:]*", r"(\g<0>)", a)
'(first):(second)'
```

`re.sub()`'s behavior makes more sense initially, but I can also understand `re.findall()`'s behavior. After all, you can match an empty string between  `first` and `:` that consists only of non-colon characters (exactly zero of them), but why isn't `re.sub()` behaving the same way?

Shouldn't the result of the last command be `(first)():(second)()`?

Comment: The documentation for `findall` says that empty matches are returned, but the documentation for `sub` doesn't say this.

Comment: @VaughnCato `re.sub('.*', 'foo', '')` returns `'foo'` though.

Comment: @VaughnCato Personally I don't feel that's a satisfying explanation. Why is the empty string even considered a match? Not like it was distinctly between other non-matches, but it could have just as well have been counted to the previous match. It's not _wrong_, but it's still not the right way to do it imo. Why not match empty strings after the `:` as well? Although I suppose this isn't the right place for these questions.

Comment: @StjepanBakrac: After the `:`, `second` is the first choice which the subpattern `[^:]*` tries.

Comment: @nhahtdh I know. Before the `:`, why is `first` not the last choice which it tries, but instead inserts a random empty string?

Comment: @StjepanBakrac: It tried `first` and found a match right away, then the match restarts at position 5, where it can only match an empty string. The engine will proceed to position 6 and restart the match, which found `second`, etc.

Comment: @nhahtdh Again, I know _how_ it works. That's not the issue. The issue is, it doesn't make sense. Adjacent empty strings should not be a separate match. The same logic you employed could be used to match fifty empty strings before the `:`. Does not make it better.

Comment: @StjepanBakrac: The thing is the engine will not start a match at a position, if it has already found a match that **starts** at the same position before. Therefore, you will get exactly 1 empty string. This is all in the implementation of the engine, and it actually doesn't make sense to argue about what a regex actually matches if we don't take into consideration the engine.

Comment: @nhahtdh You're wasting your time. I'm not arguing what it _actually_ matches. I know what it _actually_ matches. It's not hard to find out, we all have Python interpreters we can dump code into. I knew so when I posted the first comment. It still doesn't make it any better, because what it _actually_ matches is the problem. If the engine works this way, the engine is at fault.

Comment: That is what I was trying to address in my last comment. How it actually matches is defined by engine implementation. There is no well-defined definition on how matching (finding substring that matches a regex) should be done, so there are (slightly) different implementation between the engines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use the * which allows empty matches:

```
'first'   -> matched
':'       -> not in the character class but, as the pattern can be empty due 
             to the *, an empty string is matched -->''
'second'  -> matched
'$'       -> can contain an empty string before,
             an empty string is matched -->''
```

Quoting the [documentation for `re.findall()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

The reason you don't see empty matches in sub results is explained in the [documentation for `re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

> Empty matches for the pattern are replaced only when not adjacent to a previous match.

Try this:

```
re.sub('(?:Choucroute garnie)*', '#', 'ornithorynque')
```

And now this:

```
print re.sub('(?:nithorynque)*', '#', 'ornithorynque')
```

There is no consecutive #

Comment: `the sub function don't replace any empty matches that are adjacent to another match.` This seems to describe the behaviour very well. Especially for `re.sub('(?=.)', '#', 'text')` and `re.sub('^', '#', 'text')`

Answer (score 3):

The algorithms for handling empty matches are different, for some reason.

In the case of `findall`, it works like (an optimized version of) this: for every possible start index 0 <= i <= len(a), if the string matches at i, then append the match; and avoid overlapping results by using this rule: if there is a match of length m at i, don't look for the next match before i+m.  The reason your example returns `['first', '', 'second', '']` is that the empty matches are found immediately after `first` and `second`, but not after the colon --- because looking for a match starting from that position returns the full string `second`.

In the case of `sub`, the difference is, as you noticed, that it explicitly ignores matches of length 0 that occurs immediately after another match.  While I see why this might help avoid unexpected behavior of `sub`, I'm unsure why there is this difference (e.g. why wouldn't `findall` use the same rule).

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
a = "first:second:three"
print re.findall("[^:]*", a)
```

returns all substring that match pattern, here, it gives

```
>>> 
['first', '', 'second', '', 'three', '']
```

`sub()` is for substitution, and will substitute the left-most non-overlapping occurrences of pattern with your substitute. ex

```
import re
a = "first:second:three"
print re.sub("[^:]*", r"smile", a)
```

gives

```
>>> 
smile:smile:smile
```

You can command the number of occurrences to be replaced with the 4th arg, count:

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question. It would be interesting to know _why_ they behave differently.

Comment: i tried out several examples to show how both work and i do not see at all why i deserve this downvote. Maybe you should have spared your time with not writing your comment or come with your own constructive answer instead

Comment: That wasn't me. But your answer is still not related to the question.