# python re sub vs findall

Tags: python, regex

My code:

```
import urllib
import re
xml = urllib.urlopen('url').read()
```

I am interested in removing certain tags and their contents from the xml file, hence, i try using regular expressions.

for instance:

```
re.findall(r'<fig(.*?)</fig>', xml, re.DOTALL)
```

returns the matches and is non empty.

however,

```
re.sub(r'<fig(.*?)</fig>', ' ', xml, re.DOTALL)
```

does nothing, the xml string is unchanged. I am confused why, please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does re.findall() find more matches than re.sub()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371472/why-does-re-findall-find-more-matches-than-re-sub)

Comment: Just an enhancement. Shouldn't you be using at least urllib2?

Comment: I found the answer on SO by google searching the exact title of your question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 4th parameter of the [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) is not a `flags`, but a `counts`. The value of the [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) is 16 (at least in Python 2.7 / 3.4). So the `re.sub(.., re.DOTALL)` will replace only 16 times.

Specifying `flags` as a keywords argument will solve your problem:

```
re.sub(r'<fig(.*?)</fig>', ' ', xml, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

In addition to  that, `re.sub` returns a replaced string, not change the third argument in-place. Make sure you assigned back the return value of the function.

Comment: Wow! Brilliant. Thanks for the clarification! Never knew.

Comment: The same problem. I just forgot about count, again! Thank you very match.

Answer (score 0):

Since strings are immutable in python, so you have to assign the result of re.sub to a new variable. If you don't assign it to a new variable you cannot get the desired output.