# I use regular expression to extract info from a web page in python, but fail when I meet "return"?

Tags: python, regex

I want to get `www.target.com` and `target`. 
The following code works:

```
#coding: utf8
import re

info = '''<a href="www.target.com">  xxxxxx   <span>target</span>'''

result = re.findall(r'<a href="(.*?)".+?<span>(.*?)</span>', info)
print result
```

But when I meet a str, with lot of return and  char, like:

```
info = '''<a href="www.target.com"> # return here
xxxxxxxx                            # return here
xxxx                                # return here
xxxxxx   <span>target</span>'''
```

In this situation, How can I get the link `www.target.com` and  word `target` using regular expression in Python?

Comment: You can't -- regular expressions are incapable of parsing HTML. You will need to use an HTML or XML parser library instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Can you come up with *one* good reason for using regular expressions here? Python has a wonderful HTML parser ([BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)), use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turn on the DOTALL mode (`re.DOTALL`) to make dot in your regex to match even newline characters also.

> [re.DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL)
>
> Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline.

**Code:**

```
result = re.findall(r'<a href="(.*?)".+?<span>(.*?)</span>', info, re.DOTALL)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> info = '''<a href="www.target.com"> # return here
... xxxxxxxx                            # return here
... xxxx                                # return here
... xxxxxx   <span>target</span>'''
>>> re.findall(r'<a href="(.*?)".+?<span>(.*?)</span>', info, re.DOTALL)
[('www.target.com', 'target')]
```

Comment: You really should not recommend/provide solutions that parse HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: @Tomalak i agree but some high rep users also posted regex solutions to these type of questions . See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26428308/3297613

Comment: Yes, and that is equally questionable. (the downvote is not mine, btw)

Comment: The answer really solved my problem. Thank you.I read another answer about using `re` to parse Html, `it's sometimes appropriate to parse a limited, known set of HTML`