# Python bug: re.findall finds more matches than re.sub

Tags: python, regex

This is *not* about empty strings!
Already checked SO and in particular this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371472/why-does-re-findall-find-more-matches-than-re-sub)

```
s1 = '<PERSON>Desi Arnaz</PERSON> was born... intervened on <PERSON>Desi Arnaz</PERSON> behalf. <PERSON>Arnaz</PERSON> and ...'

In python:
>> re.sub("<PERSON>(Desi Arnaz|Desi Arnaz|Arnaz)</PERSON>", "----WORKED------", s1, re.IGNORECASE)
out>>'----WORKED------ was born... intervened on ----WORKED------ behalf. <PERSON>Arnaz</PERSON> and ...'

>> re.findall("<PERSON>(Desi Arnaz|Desi Arnaz|Arnaz)</PERSON>", s1, re.IGNORECASE)
out>>['Desi Arnaz', 'Desi Arnaz', 'Arnaz']
```

Can anyone confirm this bug?

Comment: It's the way you implement your group. https://eval.in/285392

Comment: You'll almost never find a bug in the actual language you're working in dude.

Comment: @Tankor: You'd be surprised.  `pathlib` is still experiencing growing pains.

Comment: @hwnd great, so reformatting your capture group changes how `re.sub` matches. Mind explaining why?

Comment: Well it has to do with his order of alternations inside of the group.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug. You've messed up the parameters passed to `re.sub`.

From the [docs on `re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

> re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)

You are however passing `re.IGNORECASE`  as the fourth (`count`) parameter, and `re.IGNORECASE` happens to be the number `2`, so only the first two matches are replaced.